# Only proceed to read XML if variable has certain value

Tags: php, xml, loops, simplexml, infinite

I have a rather simple piece of PHP code

```
$xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$response = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$status_response = $response->xpath('/PollSessionResponseDto/Status');
$answer = $status_response[0];

while ($answer<>"UpdatesComplete") {
    sleep(2);
    $answer = $response->xpath('/PollSessionResponseDto/Status')[0];
} 

$itenaries = $response->xpath('/PollSessionResponseDto/Itineraries/ItineraryApiDto');
```

I am [reading an XML file, for example](http://partners.api.skyscanner.net/apiservices/pricing/hk1/v1.0/645b3e893bed4404856a8dad8a1193c2_ecilpojl_B0B79BD58EA0D3CB97FB0E3930838587?apiKey=di712416621208689877979118676073&stops=0), and I only want to proceed to read the itenaries if status in the XML file is "UpdatesComplete". If status is "UpdatesPending", I basically want to wait 2 seconds. Then check again and wait another 2 seconds if necessary.

However I end up in an infinite loop. I checked my `$answer` variable and it seems that I am getting the string I want to check (UpdatesPending or UpdatesComplete).

Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `$answer` will **never** change inside your loop, because you never reload the XML file from the remote host.

```
do {

    $xml = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    $response = simplexml_load_string($xml);

    $answer = $response->xpath('/PollSessionResponseDto/Status')[0];

} while ($answer != "UpdatesComplete" && slee(2));
```

Comment: Thanks Sherif, makes total sense. However I am now getting an error message Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function xpath() on boolean on the line  $answer = $response->xpath('/PollSessionResponseDto/Status')[0];

Do you know why?

Comment: Since [`simplexml_load_string`](http://php.net/simplexml-load-string) returns `false` on failure, it would mean that `simplexml_load_string` failed.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.